# XSLT - Transform Xml to Xml using Xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, import, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have two xml files, I want to create a new XMl file using the first and second Xml file. I want to  modify the `<w>` node using second file node `<entite_nom >`.

First file :
[EDIT]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformation.xsl" ?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0 file:document.xsd">

    <text>
        <body>
            <p>
                <s>
                        <name>
                            <w type="NAM">Cussac</w>
                        </name>
                        <w lemma="en" type="PRP">en</w>
                        <name>
                            <w type="NAM">Haute-Vienne</w>
                        </name>
                </s>
                <s>
                    <phr type="verb_phrase" subtype="motion" function="reach">
                        <w lemma="prendre" type="VER:pres">prenez</w>
                        <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">la</w>
                        <w lemma="route" type="NOM">route</w>
                        <offset type="temporal" subtype="final">
                            <w lemma="pour" type="PRP">pour</w>
                            <w lemma="finir" type="VER:infi">finir</w>
                        </offset>
                        <w lemma="de" type="PRP">d'</w>
                        <w lemma="arriver" type="VER:infi">arriver</w>
                        <offset type="inclusion">
                            <w lemma="sur" type="PRP">sur</w>
                        </offset>
                        <name>
                            <w type="NAM">Cussac</w>
                        </name>
                    </phr>
                    <pc force="strong">.</pc>
                </s>
                <s>
                    <w lemma="il" type="PRO:PER">Il</w>
                    <phr type="verb_phrase" subtype="position">
                        <w lemma="revenir" type="VER:pres">revient</w>
                        <w lemma="tranquillement" type="ADV">tranquillement</w>
                        <offset type="inclusion">
                            <w lemma="sur" type="PRP">sur</w>
                        </offset>
                        <name>
                            <w type="NAM">Cussac</w>
                        </name>
                    </phr>
                    <pc force="strong">.</pc>
                </s>
```

I need to pick the `Id` and value of `<entite_nom>` node and add to `<w>` node of the first XMl 
Second file (`$doc2`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<geolocalisation  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="localisation-2.xsd">
   <entite_nom id="en.0" lng="0.8519611512411495" lat="45.7055740420633" alt="349.0322265625">Cussac</entite_nom>
   <entite_nom id="en.1" lng="0.859333" lat="45.712939" alt="280.5089111328125">Monnerie</entite_nom>
   <entite_nom id="en.2" lng="0.857138" lat="45.687754" alt="376.1028137207031">Liades</entite_nom>
   <entite_nom id="en.3" lng="0.8256439978387133" lat="45.67243279742165" alt="415.4050903320312">Boubon</entite_nom>
   <entite_nom id="en.4" lng="0.8219117961938217" lat="45.67606269511061" alt="420.0135498046875">Villajou</entite_nom>
   <entite_nom id="en.5" lng="0.8150905847864954" lat="45.68782102152895" alt="380.9435729980469">Puymoroux</entite_nom>
   <entite_nom id="en.6" lng="0.8519611512411495" lat="45.7055740420633" alt="349.0322265625">Cussac</entite_nom>
   <entite_nom id="en.7" lng="0.8519611512411495" lat="45.7055740420633" alt="349.0322265625">Cussac</entite_nom>   
</geolocalisation>
```

The result I'm trying to get :

```
<placeName id="en.0" 
         ref="file:fr_Cussac_coord_entites.xml">
         <name>
          <w type="NPr">Cussac</w>
         </name>
</placeName>
```

What I tried so far but i can't get the id value :

```
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="path">file:fr_Cussac-cood-entites.xml</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:key name="ref" match="entite_nom" use="."/>

    <xsl:param name="doc2" select="document('fr_Cussac-coord-entites.xml')/geolocalisation"/>  

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="tei:name[key('ref', tei:w[@type], $doc2)]">
        <placeName id="{key('ref', w[@type], $doc2)/@id}" ref="{$path}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </placeName>   
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What i get is an empty id, I can't get the id value :

```
<placeName id="" ref="file:fr_Cussac-cood-entites.xml">
            <name>
               <w type="NAM">Cussac</w>
            </name>
</placeName>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a job for a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:key name="ref" match="entite_nom" use="."/>

  <xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc('file2.xml')"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="tei:name[key('ref', tei:w[@type], $doc2)]">
     <placeName id="{key('ref', tei:w[@type], $doc2)/@id}">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </placeName> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfD/1

The use of the `key` function with a third argument to provide a context document or subtree is restricted to XSLT 2 and later.

If you expect to have several elements with the same word and want to find different ids based on the position in the document then

```
  <xsl:template match="tei:name[key('ref', tei:w[@type], $doc2)]">
     <xsl:variable name="word" select="tei:w[@type]"/>
     <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
         <xsl:number level="any" count="tei:name[tei:w[@type] = $word]"/>
     </xsl:variable>
     <placeName id="{key('ref', tei:w[@type], $doc2)[$pos]/@id}">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </placeName> 
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfD/2

In XSLT 3 it might also be possible to use a composite key or an accumulator to distinguish based on position, I am currently not sure which approach is better, the above is mainly an attempt to adjust the previous suggestion to your changed, more complex requirements.

Comment: I tried with your answer but i can't get the id value, it's empty I edited my post so you can see what I get and what I tried

Comment: @Sat, sorry, I hadn't added the `tei` prefix to the inner key call argument, now corrected. For your sample, that finds three items, not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you, it's better but I'm trying to get for the first Cussac id=en.0 and for the second Cussac id=en.6  last one id=0.7 other values are correct except Cussac.

Comment: @Sat, can you edit the input sample? Are there several `name` or `w` elements with the same value `Cussac`?

Comment: I added input sample there is 3 `w` Cussac in my file.

Comment: @Sat, fine, but please also explain how you distinguish them when relating them to the elements in the other document. Is that solely by position or by some other element or attribute value?

Comment: By their position on the text file, the first one will be `id=en.0`

Comment: @Sat, I have tried to adapt the previous suggestion to handle elements based on the position, let me know whether that does the job for your real input.

Comment: It's perfect, it's working  you are the master of XML ! :)